# Read inputCount integers from input and output "No copies of 0" if none of the integers are 0. Otherwise, output "0 present"

Tags: c++

need help with this one. It only works with some inputs, such as "3 2 1 5", the output is "no copies of 0", but when I put something like "5 0 2 4 -5 1" it's supposed to output "0 present" but instead outputs no copies of 0. But it works with inputs "1 0".

What am I missing in the for loop?

Declare a Boolean variable named noCopies. Read in an input value for variable inputCount. Then, read inputCount integers from input and output "No copies of 0" if none of the integers are 0. Otherwise, output "0 present".

Ex: If the input is 3 2 1 5, the output is:

No copies of 0

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int numVals;

   int i;
   int numS;
   bool allPositive;
   
   cin >> numVals;
   
   for (i = 0; i <= numVals; ++i) {
      
      cin >> numS;
      
      if (numS > 0) {
         allPositive = true;
      }
      else { 
         allPositive = false;
      }
   }
   if (allPositive) {
      cout << "All match" << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << "Not all match" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `inputCount` reasonably?

Comment: You're supposed to read a variable of type int in the loop, not `noCopies`, which is `bool`. Also, where is `inputCount` set?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Oops, sorry I just corrected it.

Comment: @Flin-PaoloRoxasCabagnot can't spot any corrections?

Comment: @lorro I'm new to all of this so I'm not even sure where to start. So, variables that are type into are only i and inputCount. Do I replace noCopies with either one? And how would I know which one?

Comment: You likely need to introduce one more variable to read the int.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Cin >> noCopies is wrong?

Comment: Where do you initialize `inputCount`?? The whole loop is wrong!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I already added the `cin >> inputCount;` before the for loop. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I can't spot that in your question? Sure your [edit] was saved and accepted?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I didn't know where the edit button was. I had to click on the link you posted lmao.

Comment: Besides reading into the correct variables, you have to check, whether any input is zero. There is no test for zero for each of the input numbers at all.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for the response. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @lorro I edited the code with an extra int... The code works much better, but the only problem I'm having is singling out 0's.

Comment: First you should compare with 0 / not zero (== or !=), instead of larger (>) to better account for negative numbers. Second be careful with logic. Currently you set AllPositive to true, if/when one of the inputs is larger than zero. Do it the opposite way. Assume all are positive and only if you encounter a nonpositive input, you know that the condition is false. You can do it by initializing the bool variable before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

So I am just a rookie here but I used the following code nested in my for loop after getting input and it worked great for me. I know there is probably a better way to do this though.

```
     if ( numS %2 == 0) {
     allPositive = true;
  }
  else if (numS %2 != 0) {
     allPositive = false;
  }
```

Comment: You can simplify this code to just: `allPositive = (numS % 2) == 0`.

Comment: Or `allPositive = !(numS % 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works except you need to `break;` after you declare a `false` for `allPositive` because, once it is false once, you can stop checking and end the loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int numVals;

   int i;
   int numS;
   bool allPositive;
   
   cin >> numVals;
   
   for (i = 0; i <= numVals; ++i) {
      
      cin >> numS;
      
      if (numS > 0) {
         allPositive = true;
      }
      else { 
         allPositive = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (allPositive) {
      cout << "All match" << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << "Not all match" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```